# Heroku: db upgrade in Procfile avoids deploying to new dynos

Tags: python, flask, heroku, database-migration, procfile

### Scenario

- I have a Python Flask app with a Postgres DB which I would like to deploy to multiple apps on Heroku.
- My `Procfile` assures that my database migrations are done after every build with `release: flask db upgrade`.
- I would like to automate the setup of a new app with a bunch of Heroku commands, i.e. create the app, do all the config and add the newly created app to my Heroku pipeline.

### Problem

When the new app is being built the first time, it tries to do `flask db upgrade` but the database is not yet created - so it fails. However, I usually create the database with the following Flask command from my `run.py` which is not available if the app is not build.

```
@app.cli.command()
def create_db():
    """
    Initializes the database.
    Creates all tables and indexes.
    """
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
    print("Successfully created fresh database.")
```

I guess, there is a simple solution to this "deadlock". Any suggestions are welcome.